# JSON Group by count, output to key value pair json result

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have following JSON data

```
"rows": [{  
        "createdDate": "3/11/2016",
        "createdBy": "Bob"          
    },{ 
        "createdDate": "3/12/2016",
        "createdBy": "Megan"            
    },{ 
        "createdDate": "3/12/2016",
        "createdBy": "Bob"          
    },{ 
        "createdDate": "3/13/2016",
        "createdBy": "Sam"          
    },{ 
        "createdDate": "3/11/2016",
        "createdBy": "Bob"          
    },]
```

And I want output for charting where I can group by any property name for count, for example here on 'createdBy' :

```
"result": [{
        "key": "Bob",
        "value": 3,         
    },{
        "key": "Megan",
        "value": 1,         
    },{
        "key": "Sam",
        "value": 1,         
    },
```

I have the JSON and need to manipulate it in following format before binding to my chart. I tried _groupBy from underscore but could not get desired result.

Comment: Show what you tried (in a snippet)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reduce rows to count occurences of each object by `createBy` property. `occurences` will be an object which keys are names (like `Bob1`, `Megan`, ...) and values are count of occurences. Then use `Object.keys()` to loop through this object and map it to the result:

```
var rows = [
    { 'createdDate': '3/11/2016', 'createdBy': 'Bob' },
    { 'createdDate': '3/12/2016', 'createdBy': 'Megan' },
    { 'createdDate': '3/12/2016', 'createdBy': 'Bob' },
    { 'createdDate': '3/13/2016', 'createdBy': 'Sam' },
    { 'createdDate': '3/11/2016', 'createdBy': 'Bob' },
];

var occurences = rows.reduce(function (r, row) {
    r[row.createdBy] = ++r[row.createdBy] || 1;
    return r;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(occurences).map(function (key) {
    return { key: key, value: occurences[key] };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with only one loop.

```js
var rows = [{ createdDate: "3/11/2016", createdBy: "Bob" }, { createdDate: "3/12/2016", createdBy: "Megan" }, { createdDate: "3/12/2016", createdBy: "Bob" }, { createdDate: "3/13/2016", createdBy: "Sam" }, { createdDate: "3/11/2016", createdBy: "Bob" }],
    group = function (array) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!o[a.createdBy]) {
                o[a.createdBy] = { key: a.createdBy, value: 0 };
                r.push(o[a.createdBy]);
            }
            o[a.createdBy].value++;
        });
        return r;
    }(rows);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(group, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```